# How do I select 3 character in a string after a specific symbol

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, character, variable-length

Ok, so let me explain. I have some string like this : "BAHDGF - ZZZGH1237484" or
like this "HDG54 - ZZZ1HDGET4" I want here to select the triple Z (that are obviously 3 differents character but for the example I think it's more comprehensible for you).

So, my problem is the next : The first part has a modulable length but i can just ignore it, I need something to take the triple Z so I was thinking about something that can "slice" my string after
the " - ".

I started to try using "partition" but I just failed lamentably. I just get kinda lost with the news 3 array and then take the first 3 letter of one of the array, well, it seems very complicated and i think I'm just passing by an obvious solution that I can't find actually. It's been something like 2 days that i'm on it without anything in my mind that can help me, sort of blank page syndrome actually and I really need a little help to unlock this point.

Comment: I don't use ruby but [regular expressions exist in ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html). Hopefully someone comes along to help you implement it, but that'll help you solve it. A working pattern that captures those three characters  `.*?\s-\s(.{3})` (which you can test [here](https://regex101.com/)). What you want is the first (and only) capture group from a match with that pattern.

Note that in the future, you can also just **bold** the characters you want, but your message was clear here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
examples=[ "BAHDGF - ZZZGH1237484", "HDG54 - ZZZ1HDGET4" ]
```

You could use a regex:

```
examples.each {|e| p e, e[/(?<=-\s)ZZZ/]}
```

Prints:

```
"BAHDGF - ZZZGH1237484"
"ZZZ"
"HDG54 - ZZZ1HDGET4"
"ZZZ"
```

Or `.split` with a regex:

```
examples.each {|e| p e.split(/-\s*(ZZZ)/)[1] }
'ZZZ'
'ZZZ'
```

If the 3 characters are something other than `'ZZZ'` just modify your regex:

```
> "BAHDGF - ABCGH1237484".split(/\s*-\s*([A-Z]{3})/)[1]
=> "ABC"
```

If you wanted to use `.partition` it is two steps. Easiest with a regex partition and then just take the first three characters:

```
> "BAHDGF - ABCGH1237484".partition(/\s*-\s*/)[2][0..2]
=> "ABC"
```

Answer (score 0):

"Selecting" the string `"ZZZ"` is a misnomer. What you have asked for is to determine if the string contains the substring `"- ZZZ"` and if it does, return `"ZZZ"`:

```
"BAHDGF - ZZZGH1237484".include?("- ZZZ") && "ZZZ"
  #=> "ZZZ"

"BAHDGF - ZZVGH1237484".include?("- ZZZ") && "ZZZ"
  #=> false
```

That is very little different that just asking if the string contains the substring `"- ZZZ"`:

```
if "BAHDGF - ZZZGH1237484".include?("- ZZZ")
  ...
end
```

---

If the question were instead, say, return a string of three identical capital letters following `"- "`, if present, you would be *selecting* a substring. That could be done as follows.

```
r = /- \K(\p{Lu})\1{2}/

"BAHDGF - XXXGH1237484"[r]
  #=> "XXX"

"BAHDGF - xxxGH1237484"[r]
  #=> nil
```

The regular expression reads, "match '- ', then forget everything matched so far and reset the match pointer to the current location  (`\K`), then match an upper case Unicode letter (`\p{Lu}`) and save it to capture group 1 (`(\p{Lu})`), then match the contents of capture group 1 (`\1`) twice (`{2}`)". One may alternatively use a *positive lookbehind*:

```
/(?<=- )(\p{Lu})\1{2}/
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it really helped me a lot !